# javascriptの自己再定義メソッドを代入後に使うには？

Tags: javascript

javascriptで自分を書き換えるメソッドを定義します。
このメソッドを代入してから、代入後の変数名で呼び出しても再定義が動作しません。
回避策はありますか？

```
// 自分を書き換える関数
var funcA = function(){
    console.log("A");
    funcA = function(){
        console.log("B!");
    }
};

// 代入
var funcB = funcA;

// グローバルのfuncAは再定義されるが、funcBは古いポインタを指している。
funcB();  // Aが表示される
funcB();  // またAが表示される
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

もう一階層ラップして自分を書き換える関数を返す関数

```
var funcA = (function() {
    var f = function() {
        console.log("A");
        f = function(){
            console.log("B!");
        }
    }
    return function() {
        f();
    };
})();
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
その方法でできました。

Answer (score 1):

間接参照にする。

```
var funcA = {};
funcA.fn = function(){
    console.log("A");
    funcA.fn = function(){
        console.log("B!");
    }
};
var funcB = funcA;
funcB.fn();//"A"
funcB.fn();//"B!"
```